# Getting data from AS400/IBM i through ODBC to excel

Tags: excel, odbc, ibm-midrange

I've written a very simple SQL statement on system I navigator and it shows all I need, but this statement cannot work any platform except system i navigator. When I tried to connect as400/IBM I on Excel, it does successfully connect. But the schemas and tables contain nonsense information.

My SQL statement is:

```sql
SELECT *  FROM CAPPSERV.XRFFIL02.PRDMST01
```

I can't even find the XRFFIL02 in Excel.

I've found this "[AS400 and System I Navigator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43563578/as400-and-system-i-navigator)" and tried to find my SQL name, but it shows my file name and SQL name are the same.

Maybe my direction was wrong.

Comment: If the data is garbled it might be a CCSID problem.   DSPFD the table on the IBM i.  Look for the CCSID of the table.   And DSPSYSVAL QCCSID to see the CCSID of the IBM i.